# Multicast in python is freezing my network. How to send data through socket without freezing a network?

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket
import json
from helper import sendDet

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.0.1'
MCAST_PORT = 5111
MULTICAST_TTL = 2

res = sendDet()
res = {'data': res}
res = json.dumps(res)
res = res.encode()
res = bytearray(res)


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, MULTICAST_TTL)

while True:
    sock.sendto(res, (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
```

I have used this code to send data continuously. But it is uploading at around 20MBps and freezing my network which requires restarting of my router. If I remove `while True` then it is sending only once.

Is their anyway in python which will multicast data continuously and not freezing a network?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, maybe you should expand on that. Adding `sleep(0.001)` may get you around your problem. Also if you say you need to restart your router that points at problem elsewhere, we generate over 300MBs of multicast without any problems

Comment: It is freezing your network because you flood it with UDP packets. Why would you do that anyway? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @freakish I have connected my mobile with a python program. I want to show all the devices which are connected to the same network.

Comment: @SedyVlk I feel that my router is not able to handle that much uploading. There is not much data that I am sending just 3 lines of data which I am converting to JSON and sending it continuously causing this issue.

Comment: @ShraddhaGami ok, but why are you flooding the network with a "while true" loop? Can't you send like 10 udp packets and wait for response?

Comment: @freakish I want to continuously show my device on phone the response I am receiving is through another socket event.

Comment: @ShraddhaGami and that's why everything dies. Think of it that way: say you have a friend in your house (while you are away) and you want to continuously check whether he is still there. Then you have to constantly converse with him making you and him unable to do anything else. While it is enough if you just ask him every 1min (or so) whether he is still there. That's the approach you should apply here.

Comment: Almost everything in networking is based on timeouts. Spamming packets as fast as possible is a very, very wrong way to do that. Imagine a game where every client just floods the internet with packets. Would any game be playable in such situation? In fact would anything else be usable with the internet flooded with packets? Unlikely.

Comment: If you want high resolution then send those packets every 100ms. This is faster than human reaction time but probably wont kill your network. Test it.